# Moving messages in DLQ if message processing Fails

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, message-queue, jboss7.x, mq

I have a standalone program to send message in IBM MQ. I am able to put message in Queue successfully.

```
JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

// Set the properties
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, HOST);
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, PORT);
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, CHANNEL);
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, QMGR);
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "JmsPutGet (JMS)");
cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, APP_USER);
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, APP_PASSWORD);

// Create JMS objects
context = cf.createContext();
destination = context.createQueue("queue:///" + QUEUE_NAME);

long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
TextMessage message = context.createTextMessage("Your lucky number today is " + uniqueNumber);

producer = context.createProducer();
producer.send(destination, message);
```

I have the following MDB deployed in JBoss and i reads the message from the Queue. I am explicitly throwing `throw new RuntimeException("-----------1111111111--------------");` so that message processing fails, and the message is moved to DLQ (dead letter queue). In my case exception happens and the message is getting re-delivered multiple times, and calling onMessage of EJB again and again.

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "false"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "hostName", propertyValue = "${websphere.hostName}"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "username", propertyValue = "${websphere.username}"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "password", propertyValue = "${websphere.password}"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "port", propertyValue = "${websphere.port}"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "channel", propertyValue = "${websphere.channel}"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "queueManager", propertyValue = "${websphere.queueManager}"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "${websphere.queueName}"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "transportType", propertyValue = "CLIENT"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge") })
@ResourceAdapter(value = "wmq.jmsra.rar")
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)

public class TestMDB implements MessageListener {

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {

if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
    try {
        String mqmsg = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
        System.out.println("MSG RECEIVED: " + mqmsg);
        if (uploadFile(mqmsg)) {
            System.out.println("MSG WRITE TO FILE ");
        }

        message.setJMSExpiration(1000);

        throw new RuntimeException("-----------1111111111--------------");

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}
}
}
```

I tried to find a way by setting re-try count, but failing to do so.

**What I am trying to achieve is that is it possible to set a parameter so that after lets say 2 tries, it is moved to DLQ ?**

I have been able to achieve this result for JBoss in built queue, but don't know how and where to set parameter for IBM MQ.

**I am making use of following link to run my IBM MQ as docker image:** https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-connect-app-queue-manager-containers/

I have tried the following by not able to make it work:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031670_.htm

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-specify-expiration-mq-message-and-when-expired-messages-are-removed-queue

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWMAJ_2.0.0/com.ibm.ism.doc/Developing/devjms_poisonmessages.html

More details of my sender program is here: https://developer.ibm.com/series/badge-ibm-mq-developer-essentials/

Comment: You need to define BOTHRESH and BOQNAME attributes for the MQ queue from which your MDB is getting messages.

Comment: @Shashi, I used the following link, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032280_.htm, and it worked for me.